# How to handle routes changes in flutter bloc depending on state

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a question about how to handle the authentication state in flutter bloc.

Here is my login screen code.

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getToken(context);

    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {

        if (state is Authenticated) {
          return const HomeScreen();
        }
        if (state is UnAuthenticated) {
          return const _SignInPage();
        }
        return Container(
          color: const Color(0xFFF39360),
          child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.white)),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

As you can see I'm rendering Homescreen and SignInPage depending on the state.

I am also calling a `_getToken(context);` function during build of the screen. This functions executes a loading and I get an ugly CircularProgressIndicator while it is reading the storage. If i have the token i set the state as Authenticated.

Is there a better way to handle this so I don't get the progress indicator which is not spinning when I open the application?

Thanks in advance I hope you can help me!

Comment: Can you also show the code in the bloc part? I think _getToken(context) function should be used in Bloc class.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your bloc builder code. It will render a default progress indicator till bloc emit any new state. So if you want to show indicator while your function doing some work then you should emit a loading state and handle the same in the bloc builder and if you don't want to show anything at all for default case then you can use any other widget like an empty container or Sizedbox.shrink().

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay, but every time I open the app is showing the defualt state, I have implemented a loading but it is still showing it as soon as the app opens because it is searching for the token. Is there a way to extend the time of the splash screen or something like that?